# NodeJS server crashes when querying MySQL database with "Incorrect arguments" to throw error

Tags: mysql, node.js, server, crash

While trying to query a local MySQL database, I encounter the following error:

```
..\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^
Incorrect arguments
```

No further information is provided after that.
I've looked up the already available solutions such as adding:

```
con.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log("[mysql error]",err);
});
```

or even replacing (the only) `throw err` in the code with `console.log(err);` but none did the trick.

The server eventually crashes once the error is displayed, and it happens after the `console.log('Query res: ', results);` in the code below, meaning that the request has been successful and has fetched the wanted data.

As I see it, it could be caused by *bcrypt*, but the error comes from the *MySQL node.js* package as seen in the logs.

**loginroutes.js:**

```
exports.login = function(req, res) {
    console.log("email:", req.body.email, "password:", req.body.password);
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    con.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", [email], (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error ocurred");
            res.send({"code":400, "failed":"error occurred"});
        } else {
            console.log('Query res: ', results);
            if (results.length > 0) {
                if (bcrypt.compareSync(results.password, password))
                    res.send({"code":200, "success":"login successful"});
                else
                    res.send({"code":204, "success":"email & password combination does not match"});
            } else
                res.send({"code":204, "success":"email does not exist"});
        }
    });
};
```

What is it I missed and what can I do to solve that issue ?

Thank you.

**EDIT:** also tried with `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = \"" + email + "\""` just for the sake of it, it turns out similar to the previous request.

Comment: There could be an escaping issue with the mail address. Can you try with `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = " + mysql.escape(email)` instead

Comment: put `return` keyword before res.send. `return res.send({"code":400, "failed":"error occurred"});`

Comment: @Berkays that solved the crash issue, but for some reason `results` appears empty when logged (it wasn't previously). What could be the reason behind it ?

Comment: @front_end_dev I added a `return` before every `res.send()` as you suggested and now the server crashes just by reloading the login page.

Comment: @ilomax does the query work as expected if you execute it directly in mysql interface?

Comment: @Berkays Yes it does. The query actually works, the content of `results` is correct, the server just crashes at some point after the `console.log('Query res: ', results);`

Answer (score 0):

To log any exception in the code you need to put the code block inside `try catch`

```
try {
  // your code here
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  res.send({ code:400, failed: "error occurred"});
}
```

please try this code and paste error here.

Comment: I've encapsulated the whole inside of my `con.query()`, from above the `if (err)` statement down to after the `res.send("code":204...)` in a `try`.
All I've got from `catch` is a the exact same behaviour as previously described but the error is now only "Incorrect arguments", without the `throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^`

Comment: can you please post complete logs of results you are getting.